# what does "re-seed ocean" mean

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm reading this article: https://qr.ae/TWFMUj

> We must also take steps to reverse the damage we’ve done to our
>   environment through planting trees and **re-seeding oceans**.

What does "re-seeding oceans" mean?
Does this mean, you put sea weed seeds in oceans?

Comment: to get plant life and coral to grow once again in the ocean, when there isn't any.

Comment: google coral reef restoration and you will find lots of information about it.

Answer (score 1):

Re-seeding *literally* means to sow seed in an area that has previously had flora growing but has become bare, or patchy.

In a wider context, it refers to refreshing or replenishing anything by encouraging natural growth. It could apply to flora or fauna (so in relation to oceans it could include fish, not just plants) and is different from "repopulating".

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the article you link to isn't clear. I suspect that this is at least partly metaphorical, but it could mean either fauna or flora or possibly both. I think that in this context it is sufficient to take this as meaning "repairing" the seas, in a manner to be determined by someone better qualified than the author.